# Creating a correct loop structure to populate a list of objects

Tags: java, loops, object, arraylist, populate

I have a list of objects, each has two fields, name and weight. I need to populate and calculate the weights from those list that will fulfill a parameter of an object in list of other objects, however it must create this new objects only when the sum of weight doesn't exceed the maximum, then it moves on, calculates another weight from the first list until maximum and then create an object with a needed parameter for the other list, this is what it looks like in a code.

This is the first list:

```
[Item{name='building tools', weight=2000}, Item{name='building tools', weight=2000}, Item{name='building tools', weight=2000}, Item{name='building tools', weight=5000}, Item{name='building tools', weight=5000}, Item{name='building tools', weight=2000}, Item{name='building tools', weight=1000}, Item{name='building tools', weight=5000}, Item{name='building tools', weight=6000}, Item{name='shelter equipment', weight=5000}, Item{name='construction equipment', weight=5000}, Item{name='plants', weight=1000}, Item{name='steel', weight=8000}, Item{name='books', weight=1000}, Item{name='water', weight=5000}]
```

Now I am creating a loop that takes the weights into separate variable until its less than 8000, then I need to populate other list of objects, where one of the paramether is the weight of those items and it cannot be greater than 8000, this is how it looks like in a code:

```
 public List<Rocket> loadU1(List<Item> items) {

        List<Rocket> u1Rockets = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            if ( testWeight + items.get(i).getWeight() <= 8000) {
                testWeight += items.get(i).getWeight();
            } else {
                u1Rockets.add(new U1(120, 10000, 18000, testWeight));
                testWeight = 0;
            }
    }
    return u1Rockets;

}
```

testWeight is the calculation variable its a global int variable in the class. The constructor for a new u1Rocket has everything static except the last parameter which is the weight which cannot exceed 8000. When I run loadU1, this is however how it looks populated:

```
[U1{cost=120, weight=10000, maxWeight=18000, weightOfCargo=6000}, U1{cost=120, weight=10000, maxWeight=18000, weightOfCargo=8000}, U1{cost=120, weight=10000, maxWeight=18000, weightOfCargo=6000}, U1{cost=120, weight=10000, maxWeight=18000, weightOfCargo=6000}]
```

It works just fine until i=3, then it of course sets testWeight to 0, so it could calculate it over but then doesn't creates a new rocket object with 5000 as it should because the one after 5000 (i = 4) is also 5000 which exceeds the limit so it should create separate Rocket with 5000 for this one and then of course go on... I am trying to debug it but cannot find out where is the exact logical problem from my side, thanks.

So this is my Rocket class,

```
public class Rocket implements Spaceship {
    private int price;
    private int weight;
    private int weightOfCrago;
    private int maxWeight;

    public Rocket(int price, int weight, int weightOfCrago, int maxWeight) {
        this.price = price;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.weightOfCrago = weightOfCrago;
        this.maxWeight = maxWeight;
    }

    public Rocket() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean launch() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean land() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canCarry(Item item) {
        if ((item.getWeight() + weightOfCrago) <= (maxWeight - weight)){
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void carry(Item item) {
        maxWeight += item.getWeight();

    }
```

Couldn't for example somehow the canCarry method be used before creation in the loop I have posted before to prevent from creating a new Rocket object that exceeds the limit ? The U1 is a child of a Rocket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your code simply skips the currently checked item when the rocket is already full.

The fastest way to solve this would be to return to the skipped position whenever a rocket is created (thus `i--`). But you also always skip the last bucket, so you must still add it. See:

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    if (testWeight + items.get(i).getWeight() <= 8000) {
        testWeight += items.get(i).getWeight();
    } else {
        u1Rockets.add(new U1(120, 10000, 18000, testWeight));
        testWeight = 0;
        // re-check the skipped item
        i--;
    }
}

// add the last rocket
u1Rockets.add(new U1(120, 10000, 18000, testWeight));
```

Note that you have  a variation of the [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) on your hands here, an NP-complete problem.

Comment: But now it adds a new rocket object for each weight value of items list, which is not what i want. I want to add it after the weight is at max to 8000,  if it's not and the next weight exceeds it, then it creates a new rocket object... Couldn't I solve it somehow to perhaps add some method to a Rocket object that would check if the Rocket object doesn't exceeds the max limit ? I will add some code to a post.

Comment: Have you maybe misplaced a curly parenthesis? The code as posted should not do that.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :) [Please accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)